# Constraint limit of items through rules in firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In firebase realtime database, can we limit number of items fetched from a node through rules?

We have `limitToFirst` and `limitToLast` methods on client sdk, but can we manage it through rules as well to ensure security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

Example from documentation:

```
messages: {
  ".read": "query.orderByKey &&
            query.limitToFirst <= 1000"
}

// Example queries:

db.ref("messages").on("value", cb)                // Would fail with PermissionDenied

db.ref("messages").limitToFirst(1000)
                  .on("value", cb)                // Would succeed (default order by key)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data